# Excel VBA SQL Query with variable values that may be blank

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to get an SQL query to work in Excel.
In the worksheet I have a list of 5 numbers(one in a cell). I have the query working where if there is a number in all 5 cells it works fine. However I need it to still run if the cell is blank. e.g. only 3 cells with numbers in.

Is there any way to do this?

My code is for example:

```
var1 = worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
var2 = worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
var3 = worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
var4 = worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4")

Select * from Schema.Table WHERE column1 = " & var1 & " AND (column1 = " & var2 & " etc....
```

Any way to code this so if var3 is blank it is excluded from the SQL query?

Thanks

Comment: May column3 in that case have any value, or must it be empty or 0?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is easy:

```
Dim szSQL As String

szSQL = "select * from Schema.Table WHERE "
If (var1 <> "") Then szSQL = szSQL & "column1 = " & var1
If (var1 <> "" And var2 <> "") Then szSQL = szSQL & " AND "
If (var2 <> "") Then szSQL & " column2 = " & var2
```

Comment: your solution will be very complex if 4 variables are used, which is the case in this question.
Also, if all variables are empty, you can't use WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0
sqltext = 'Select * from Schema.Table '

if var1 <> '' then
   counter = counter + 1
   if counter > 1 then
     sqltext = sqltext & ' and column1 = ' & var1
   else
     sqltext = sqltext & ' where column1 = ' & var1
   end if
end if
if var2 <> '' then
   counter = counter + 1
   if counter > 1 then
     sqltext = sqltext & ' and column2 = ' & var2
   else
     sqltext = sqltext & ' where column2 = ' & var2
   end if
end if
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

I would build all the condition in an array and the use `Join` to format the final query:

```
Sub BuildQuery()
  Dim headers(), values(), conditions(), value, i&, ii&

  ' load the headers and values in an array '
  headers = VBA.Array("column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5")
  values = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5").value

  ' create each condition for each non empty value '
  ReDim conditions(0 To UBound(headers))
  For Each value In values
    If Len(value) Then
      conditions(ii) = headers(i) & " = " & value
      ii = ii + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Next
  ReDim Preserve conditions(0 To ii - 1)

  ' build the final query '
  Debug.Print "Select * from Schema.Table WHERE " & Join(conditions, " And ")
End Sub
```